# Реализация DataTemplateSelector в UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

пытаюсь реализовать DataTemplateSelector в UWP, но VS постоянно мозги  мне морочит с ошибками не найдено имя типа, которые написаны в этом же каталоге и подключены

```
<Page
x:Class="TestUWP.Pages.WorkDB.Main"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestUWP.Pages.WorkDB"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"

xmlns:mapobjects="using:TestUWP.Pages.WorkDB.Modules"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DescPointConnection" x:DataType="mapobjects:PointConnection">

    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DescSpan" x:DataType="mapobjects:Span">

    </DataTemplate>

    <local:DescDataTemplateSelector x:Key="DescSelector" 
                                            DTPointConnection="{StaticResource DescPointConnection}"
                                            DTSpan="{StaticResource DescSpan}"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

сам селектор создал по шаблонам что нашёл в интернете

```
public class DescDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate DTPointConnection { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate DTSpan { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                var convItem = (MapObject)item;
                switch (convItem.GetType().ToString())
                {
                    case "PointConnection":
                        return DTPointConnection;
                    case "Span":
                        return DTSpan;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return base.SelectTemplateCore(item);
        }

        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            return SelectTemplateCore(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: В вашем случае DataTemplateSelector не нужен

Comment: почему? просто у меня будет несколько подвидов реализации datatemplate и простого изменения по тригеру будет мало, т.к. будут использоватся разные типы объектов, и их будет несколько, да и сам селектор интересен, вопрос только в том почему он не хочет работать

Comment: Ок, DataTemplateSelector лежит в пространстве имен `TestUWP.Pages.WorkDB`? Попробуйте удалить из XAML строчку `<local:DescDataTemplateSelector ...` и скомпилировать проект, если нормально скомпилируется — добавьте ее снова и скомпилируйте еще раз

Comment: теперь появляется синтаксическая ошибка на свойства datatype в datatemplate, что лежат в ресурсах страницы, поискал на это решение и теперь просят создать отдельный файл словарь ресурсов

Comment: сделал как просили, в результате на селектор пока не обращает внимание, зато datatype просто блокирует синтаксической ошибкой                                                        
The XAML Binary Format (XBF) generator reported syntax error '0x09C4' : Property Not Found, той же на которую майки написали решение кому-то, которое реализовал и я

Comment: оказалось надо было просто реализовать сами datatemplate, а не оставлять их пустыми

Comment: Ах, ну конечно, я-то думал вы не привели сами шаблоны чтобы сократить код, а у вас их вообще не было

Comment: кто ж знал, ну зато сам смог разобраться с проблемой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

объекты DataTemplate требуют реализации при указании поля DataType.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Key" x:DataType="Type">
   <TextBlock Text="Visual Studio не ответит на ваши вопросы!"/>
</DataTemplate>
```